# Conditional ES6 import and export

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6, import

How to write a nested if else for import and export in ES6. Here I have 2 files, production.js  and development.js having separately keys for development code and production code and another file keys.js which imports and exports them as per the requirement.All 3 files lie in same directory.

**Note, package.json says type : "module".**

**production.js**

```
const keys = {
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    mongoURI : process.env.MONGO_URI,
    cookieKey : process.env.COOKIE_KEY
}

export default keys;
```

**development.js**

```
const keys = {
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID : 'something.something',
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET : 'itisasecret',
    mongoURI : 'database',
    cookieKey : 'blabla',
}

export default keys;
```

**keys.js**

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    
    /*This section throws error*/
    
    import keys from './production.js'
    export default keys
}
else{

    /*This section also throws error*/

    import keys from './development.js'
    export default keys
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to write a nested if/else to dynamically import a module, but you do have to use the dynamic import syntax. The reasons for this is because the `import` statement only takes a single or double quoted string that is a path to the module to import. If you use the dynamic syntax using `import()` (looks like a function but isn't really) then within the parentheses you can put a string template literal to pull in the file you need.

The downside is that `import()` returns a Promise object that you have to deal with. But that isn't too difficult.

Here is your solution:

index.js

```
import keys from './keys.js';
console.log(keys);
```

production.js

```
const keys = { stuff: 'production' }
export default keys;
```

development.js

```
const keys = { stuff: 'development' }
export default keys;
```

keys.js

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
let keys;
(async ()=>{
  try {
    keys = import( `./${process.env.NODE_ENV}.js`);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})();
export default await keys;
```

Note the use of the async code here to deal with the Promise object. Also the `try/catch` should always wrap an `await` statement in order to handle any Promise rejection.

Used in this manner, there is no requirement for if/else conditional logic.

Finally, a working repl to demonstrate this working. But, in order for this to work on the repl:

1. On the right panel select the shell tab
2. run this command in the shell: `npx node@14 index.js`

If you just hit the `Run` button at the top of the page it won't work and you'll see errors about `import`.

[Working Example](https://repl.it/@randycasburn/SyncEventsInNode-1#index.js)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it doesn't work that way. What you're describing is basically a dynamic import.

Import both key sets from both files.
Then create an object that maps the keys based on the `NODE_ENV` values.
Select the keys and export.

```js
import productionKeys from './production.js'
import developmentKeys from './development.js'

const keys = {
  'production': productionKeys,
  'development': developmentKeys
};

const selectedKeys = keys[process.env.NODE_ENV];

export default selectedKeys;
```

Comment: Well this certainly won't work if this code was to be deployed, as because I wasn't committing development.js (secret codes) to lets say heroku. Hence the server would definitely want to find developmentKeys from 'development.js' and on not finding them would throw me an error.

Comment: Then why should the files named differently? Just create a file called `keys.js' and have different values on your production environment and on your development environment. Ignore the file from commits and place it manually on both environments.

Comment: Yes exactly what I did later on.